# which partitions encrypt?

Tags: partition, disk-encryption

Time to encrypt.
My setup:

- `/boot` [1 gb]
- LVM

  - `swap` [4 gb]
  - `/root` [30 gb]
  - `/usr` [4 gb]
  - `/var` [4 gb]
  - `/home` [150 gb]
  - `/tmp` & `/var/tmp` [2 gb]

At first gonna encrypt `swap` & `/home`, but not sure if its better encrypt some other too.

*(the aim is cyber-security, don't encrypt all disk by performance reasons, an aged laptop)*

Also not 100% sure if space distribution is the best.

*(Debian PC, not server.)*

Comment: What to encrypt totally depends on what data you need to protect. Do you need your `/bin/ls` encrypted? What about your mail in `/var/mail`? Are you protecting the data on a running system from intrusion attempts (someone accessing your account or the root account), or data on a powered-off system (someone stealing the physical machine)?

Comment: thx for feedback. Why encrypt `/bin/ls`? In general Im protecting on all that cases, but aiming against someone injecting malware from distance (internet, intruder in home network, etc)

Comment: I don't really see how encryption would protect against malware. When you're using the system, you are using the decrypted data, which means that if you run some form of malware, this malware would also be able to access the decrypted data. Disk encryption is more useful as a privacy measure in case of theft. I'd be more concerned about protecting against intrusion if you want to protect a running system.

Comment: well that's why I isolated some mount points in partitions, for security. However its not the only measure, only one of the steps. Any advice is welcome ofc.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using LVM, the usual configuration is to set encryption on the physical volume level so all logical volumes are encrypted.

This is how typical encrypted LVM setup looks in Fedora:

```
sda                                             8:0    0 931,5G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0     1G  0 part  /boot
└─sda2                                          8:2    0 930,5G  0 part  
  └─luks-094c2ba3-eb59-48fe-83ab-eca3fe533c03 253:0    0 930,5G  0 crypt 
    ├─fedora-root                             253:1    0    70G  0 lvm   /
    ├─fedora-swap                             253:2    0   7,9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─fedora-home                             253:3    0 852,6G  0 lvm   /home
```

I have only three LVs (for `/`, `/home` and swap) but everything except `/boot` is encrypted. It's also much easier to encrypt on the PV level than encrypting individual LVs.

Answer (score 0):

Encrypting your data at the filesystem level is unlikely to protect you from anything on a system that is up and running.  Once the system is booted and the filesystems are mounted, the data is available to anyone logged in, barring file-level permissions, and a breach of root would get around that anyway.

You could encrypt specific filesystems (ie. /home/mydir) and only mount them when you are using them, then unmounting them when you log out, but that's a hassle you're unlikely going to want to live with ... and, if someone were to hack in while you were logged in, they'd have access to those filesystems as well.

Disk encryption is realistically only useful for the physical theft of the storage device.  When the crook tries to access the drive, they would need the key to decrypt it.